# Mysql insert data in existing table. how to automaticly give the data new id if already exists

Tags: mysql, sql-update, unique-index

I had two tables running in 2 different databases but the structure is identical. I want to import data of one table into the other but the id of the rows was autoincrement. This causes id's in both tables to have the same value but their content is different.
How do I insert the content of table1 into table 2 and auto update the id to a value that doesnt exist yet?

Because the table contains around 1000 rows I can't manually change the numbers or declare each individual row.
Something like `ON DUPLICATE 'id' AUTO INCREMENT 'id'`
?

Comment: Do you need to maintain the IDs from table 1?  If not, just do an INSERT...SELECT into table 2 from table 1, and ignore the IDs from table 1, letting it autoincrement those upon insert.

Comment: @Namrehs your are right

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this could be the way

```
Hitesh> desc test;
+-------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| name  | varchar(200) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| id    | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
+-------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)

Hitesh> desc test_new;
+-------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| name  | varchar(200) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| id    | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
+-------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)

Hitesh> insert into test_new(name) select name from test;
Query OK, 9 rows affected (0.03 sec)
Records: 9  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

Hitesh> select * from test_new;
+-------------------------+----+
| name                    | id |
+-------------------------+----+
| i am the boss           |  1 |
| You will get soon       |  2 |
| Happy birthday bro      |  3 |
| the beautiful girl      |  4 |
| oyee its sunday         |  5 |
| cat and dog in a park   |  6 |
| dog and cat are playing |  7 |
| cat                     |  8 |
| dog                     |  9 |
+-------------------------+----+
9 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: I fixed it by inserting the 1000 rows from table 1 into a new table1_new into the second database. That way I didn't need to adjust the exported query. I used 
`INSERT INTO junction_collections_table2 (row2, row3, row4) SELECT row2, row3, row4 FROM table1_new.`

Row1 was the id, so now mysql will autoincrement the id's for the inserted rows.
I figured this out because of Hiteshes query, Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

> INSERT INTO new_db.new_tbl SELECT * FROM old_db.old_tbl;

Above will not generate new ids for new_tbl.

Let me explain it a little further, we consider you have both tables with id as auto increment enabled.

**Override the auto increments**

`insert into B select * from A;`

- If you insert a value into new_tbl's (B) id column. i.e. if you select all columns, This will override the auto increment for the new table.

**Activate the auto increment**

`insert into B (col1, col2) select col1, col2 from A;`

`insert into B select 0, col1, col2 from A;`

- If you want activate the auto increment on new_tbl (B) you can not pass ids to the insert stmnt, so you will need to skip the id (chose the columns you want to migrate without id column) or send `DEFAULT`/`NULL`/`0` for the id.